# Where do i place the 'Max' function in my SQL query to display the most recent 'LastCallBack'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My boss has asked me to place a 'Max' function of somesort into my statement so that when the table displays it comes up with the most recent 'LastCallBack' , I am not looking for a answer just someone to give me some guidance on this as i've searched SO and can't find something to answer my question. 
Here is my code.

```
    Select Cdf_Code_Tx, ProjectNo, Convert (Date, [Last Call Back], 103) 
              As LastCallBack, (CDF_New_des1_Tx+CDF_New_des2_Tx) As Description

    From Products

    Inner Join SpecDetails

    On CDF_Code_Tx = ProductRef

    Inner Join Projects2

    On ProjectNo = PID 

    Order By Convert (Date, [Last Call Back], 103) Desc
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check the documentation on `MAX`? What did you try? Just by placing the cursor on a keyword and pressing F1 SSMS will display the syntax

Comment: Do you want the most recent or the maximum? Changes to/from daylight saving time have a way of complicating things.

Comment: I've searched SO , W3Schools & a few other websites like Lynda Videos etc & none really explain how i could use the MAX.

Comment: I would like the most recent but i am told it's something to do with 'MAX' syntax.

Comment: You're almost there...you can simply "SELECT TOP 1 ...", since you are already ordering by the most recent.  Also, I'd change your "Order by" to "Order by [Last Call Back]" without converting it, so that the TIME is included in the ordering.

Comment: Just tried that & it's not seem to be working as i needed to convert [Last Call Back]

Comment: How about _not_ converting the date to a string in the `ORDER BY` clause? Once it becomes dd/mm/yyyy and you alphabetize it the result won't be what you want.

Comment: Last call back per product, per project, overall?

Comment: Last Call Back per Product @StefanSteinegger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a where condition like:

```
WHERE [Last Call Back] = (SELECT MAX([Last Call Back]) 
                            FROM table_where_last_call_back_column_is)
```

Comment: I just tried this line of code but it appears ' Incorrect Syntax Near Where ' on any line of the code i place it on.

Comment: Re arranged this for a little bit & it gave em the guidance i needed  , thank you :)

Comment: this was the purpose of my answer, you asked for guidance. Glad it helped :)